# Simple algorithm to check for and delete (change to zero) 3 or more adjacent elements in 2D array of integers

Tags: arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to make a brick shooter game, where you have a board (2D array of int) and a set of bricks on each side. For example, I have bricks of 3 colors represented by numbers 1, 2, 3 and I put them in random locations on the board. When player shoots one brick from a side of the board it goes straight to the first brick it meets on the board or to the edge.

The problem is when 3 or more bricks of the same color are adjacent, they have to be deleted. I don't quite know how to implement that... Programming language you choose doesn't matter if it's possible to see the logic behind that code for a beginner like me.

...and also it is my first question on the site, so don't attack me if something's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for, is an adjacency matrix, in which you will tell every block, which color has the adjacent block.

In that way will be easy for you to know if the blocks have the same color. If you don't know what an adjacency matrix is, I will put a link for you, in order to learn how they work.

https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/adjacency-matrix

This should help you, to overcome your problem.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to implement a flood fill algorithm. This will find all blocks attached to the hit block, and all the blocks attached to those, and all... etc.

Here, a cell is a discrete space in the array, e.g. position [n, m] in the array.

1. Insert into *active*, the seed cell (hit block)
2. Select any cell **c** from *active*
3. Insert **c** into *closed*, and remove from *active*
4. Insert into *active* the matching-value adjacent neighbours of **c** NOT in *closed* or *active*
5. If *active* has cells, move to step 2, else continue
6. All values in *closed* can be deleted